# Open external link by clicking read more button on Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink

There is a `read more` button after excerpt of post on homepage. When clicking on it is opening full article.

For second scenario I have created custom field `external_readmore`

If `external_readmore` field is filled with some link then read more should open that link.

If `external_readmore` field is empty, then `read more` button should open full article

```
if(!empty($external_readmore)) {
                the_content('', false);
                echo ('<span class="more-text"><a href="$external_readmore">Read more...</a></span>')
                } else {
                the_content('<span class="more-text">Read more</span>', 0, true )
                }
```

What I did wrong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($external_readmore)) {
   the_content('', false);
   echo '<span class="more-text"><a href="' . $external_readmore . '">Read more...</a></span>';
} else {
   the_content('<span class="more-text">Read more</span>', 0, true );
}
```

Use `isset` function instead and DON't use `(` & `)` around echo, and close it with `;`. and the variable `$external_readmore` has to be enclosed by `' .` and `. '`

Comment: Thank you very much @JoranDenHouting. Those were very silly and obvious mistakes... But still it is not working. I guess I did something wrong while trying to get link from WordPress custom field `$external_readmore = wp_get_post_meta(the_ID(), 'external_readmore', true);`